# Arduino Lily Pad mp3, Loop in Loop in Loop with timing

Tags: c++, random, arduino, nested-loops

the best way to explain my problem is in codeform.

```
    const int ringerPin = A0;
    const int offhook = A4;
    const int onhook = A5;

    void setup(){
    pinMode(ringerPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(offhook, INPUT);
    pinMode(onhook, INPUT);
    randomSeed(analogRead(0));

  }

  int randCall = random(60000, 3600000); // generate a random number between 1 min and 60 min

//ring every 1 to 60 minutes if the phone is down (hookon) and dont ring if the phone is picked up (no hookon)
void loop()
{
  if (digitalRead(hookon) == HIGH)

void loop(){
delay(randCall);

      //i dont know how to let this loop below here run for 30 seconds.
 void loop()
    {
      //turn audio off - i dont know how to.
    for(int x = 0; x < 15; x++){
      digitalWrite(ringerPin, HIGH);   
      delay(50);                           
      digitalWrite(ringerPin, LOW);   
      delay(80); 
    }
    delay(2500);
    }
  else
    //play one randomly choosen audiofile out of 10 - i dont know how to
}
}
```

I would be greatful if there is anybody who can give me some suggestions to my coding problems.?
I wrote them inside the code descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

`loop()` is not a way to create a loop. `loop()` is the function that Arduino calls over and over when it can.

To create loops, use `while` or `for`. You can think of the `loop()` function as being the body of a `while(true)` loop.

That said, you should probably not use loops for what you are trying to do. There is a useful function called `millis()` that returns the number of milliseconds since the device was turned on. The value overflows every 50 days. You will need to handle that, but I suggest you write the `loop()` function to check if enough time has passed, and then do what it is supposed to. See [this](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay) for an example.